# What is the maximum size of an indexedDB database in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, indexeddb, web-storage

So far I have:

Firefox: unlimited

Safari: 50MB (and uses web sql instead of idb)

Chrome: unlimited

Opera: unlimited

IE: ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For IE10 you can find an awnser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717739/storage-limit-for-indexeddb-on-ie10). You will see that the normal limit is 250mb, but as user you can increase it until 999 mb per domain. How to is described in the post.

Comment: cool, thanks. any idea if this limit is imposed on the File API too? so we have 1GB in indexedDB but also some text files set up in like a tree which we can use for additional storage space?

Comment: I think it is for both together

Comment: As of IE11 at least, this has nothing to do with Indexeddb space and is the value for Temporary Internet Files. The caches and databases tab (IE11) is where you can see what storage space is being used and what point you get prompted. Unfortunately doesn't let you increase the maximum though.

Answer (score 1):

IE10 allows up to 10mb of combined AppCache and IndexedDB without prompting, once you hit that level you will be asked if you want to allow it to be increased up to a max of 250mb *per site*.