# indexedDB: Internet Explorer 11 gives AbortError when defining 40+ indexes for an object store

Tags: internet-explorer-11, indexeddb

When in the onUpgradeNeeded block, I create the objectStore and 43 indexes for that store. IE11 gives an AbortError when Chrome and Firefox can create the ObjectStore.

If I reduce the number of indexes (e.g. to 30) it works in IE11 fine.

Any idea what could be causing this?

```
dbOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event)
{
    console.log("Upgrading");

    //Get the resulting DB from the Open Request
    indDB = dbOpenRequest.result;

    var versionNum = event.oldVersion;

    //First time the request is made.
    if (!(versionNum < 1)) 
    {
        console.log("Deleting Old Version");
        indDB.deleteObjectStore("storename");
    }

    console.log("Creating Object Store");

    // Create the object store to hold the information. The "Primary Key" is specified here.
    dbObjectStore = indDB.createObjectStore("storename", { keyPath : "storePrimaryKey" });

    // Visit Details
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("one", "one", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("two", "two", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("three", "three", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("four", "four", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("five", "five", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("six", "six", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("seven", "seven", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("eight", "eight", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("nine", "nine", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("ten", "ten", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("eleven", "eleven", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twelve", "twelve", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirteen", "thirteen", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("fourteen", "fourteen", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("fifteen", "fifteen", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("sixteen", "sixteen", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("seventeen", "seventeen", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("eighteen", "eighteen", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("ninteen", "ninteen", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twenty", "twenty", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentyone", "twentyone", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentytwo", "twentytwo", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentythree", "twentythree", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentyfour", "twentyfour", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentyfive", "twentyfive", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentysix", "twentysix", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentyseven", "twentyseven", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentyeight", "twentyeight", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("twentynine", "twentynine", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirty", "thirty", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtyone", "thirtyone", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtytwo", "thirtytwo", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtythree", "thirtythree", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtyfour", "thirtyfour", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtyfive", "thirtyfive", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtysix", "thirtysix", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtyseven", "thirtyseven", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtyeight", "thirtyeight", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("thirtynine", "thirtynine", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("forty", "forty", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("fortyone", "fortyone", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("fortytwo", "fortytwo", { unique: false });
    dbObjectStore.createIndex("fortythree", "fortythree", { unique: false });
    console.log("Object Store Setup Complete");
};
```

Comment: Take a look on the limitations of size/quantity of indexes. I couldn't find it witha  quick search, but you might be able to invest more time on that than I do :)

Comment: Yeah I was looking around for limitations on this but didn't find anything on it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I do not know this technology, I got here by accident. But this kind of answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717739/storage-limit-for-indexeddb-on-ie10

Comment: I saw that one before but it's not an actual limit on the data that I'm putting into it, but a limit on the structure of the DB. It's only about 300-400kb I think.

Comment: Hm, that is a pitty. Sorry, I can't help you anymore, Good luck!

Comment: There is no limit on the number of indexes in the spec. This is likely a bug in IE and you should report it to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1464528/indexeddb-createindex-fails-if-more-than-42-indexes) this that index limitation in IE, which is not according to spec.

Anyways, do you really need 42 index, I sense something inappropriate use case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug report. I have seen one similar to this before but not so specific to my problem. It seems IE will just not be able to handle it. This is for a large scale data capturing application. I will have 100+ indexes over a fair few object stores when done. I have found that the error manifests itself when defining this many indexes over a few object store also, so I can't just split them out.

Comment: you know that index is only need if you want to range query or ordering on the index. Generally you can just store the object without indexing.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you can define where the data goes without defining an index? I've never seen storing of data in an object store without using indexes.

Comment: Ah you can just do a .add() without defining the indexes and it creates the keys for you. Thanks Kyaw.